# Can I configure startup and shutdown logs for Spring Boot applications?

Tags: logging, spring-boot, app-startup

For the ability to verify the startup and shutdown of our Spring Boot applications we want to configure a startup.log and shutdown.log capturing events that bootstrap and shutdown the application.

For startup everything up to:

```
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in {x} ms
```

And for shutdown everything from:

```
Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53bd8fca: startup date [Wed Aug 19 09:47:10 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

to the end.

Is this something that is container specific? (Tomcat vs Jetty vs Undertow)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an event listener that watches for `ApplicationReadyEvent` and `ContextStoppedEvent` and log whatever you want.

```
@Service
public class Foo {

    @EventListener
    public void onStartup(ApplicationReadyEvent event) { ... }

    @EventListener
    public void onShutdown(ContextStoppedEvent event) { .... }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

We use `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` to log startup and shutdown:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @PostConstruct
    public void startupApplication() {
        // log startup
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownApplication() {
        // log shutdown
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can combine [EventListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html) with [ApplicationReadyEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html) and [ContextStoppedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStoppedEvent.html).

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStoppedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class StartupShutdownEventListener {

  @EventListener
  void onStartup(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    // do sth
  }

  @EventListener
  void onShutdown(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```

*Note*: Answer provided by Stephane Nicoll does contain the same (correct) information, but I wanted to provide an valid Java example.